# How to provide a drop-down list for Tableau users to choose columns for download in a cross-tab

Tags: tableau-api

I've given users access to a dashboard with data output from a custom SQL query. The query pulls in over 20 fields, however, when the user downloads the data to a crosstab, they want to choose which columns to include.  I've seen that you can use parameters to filter out fields(https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/changing-views-using-parameters.htm), however, this example shows how to use parameters to create a drop down for a single column select.  If I have 20 columns, I'd like the user to choose any combination they like, whether it's one,some or all of the columns.  Based on the Tableau link I found, it seems like maybe it's possible to do so by using a CASE statement but adding compound statements for multiple columns.  However, with 20 columns, the permutations of CASE statements would be huge.  Is there an easier, more efficient way to do this?

To make sure I'm clear, I have a number of Dimensions, no Measures in my crosstab, and I'd like the user to select from the Dimensions for the crosstab download

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For a crosstab, I accomplish this by placing <kbd>Measure Names</kbd> on the *Filters* shelf and displaying the filter. This gives the user the ability to show/hide which measure they want to view and download.

Place <kbd>Measure Names</kbd> on the *Filters* shelf:

[image: Measure Name on Filter Shelf]

Show/Hide Columns in Crosstab:

[image: Show/Hide Columns in Crosstab]

Comment: For my crosstab, all of the columns are dimensions, there are no measures.  Would this still work?  Also, how do you create the Measure Names filter?  Is it a customer parameter?

Comment: Actually, I see that Measure Names is in dimensions, but as I said before, my crosstab is a collection of all Dimensions, so I don't think your solution will work, right?

Comment: Now I see. The only other option I can think of aside from the parameter with 'CASE' Statement is if you can change the data structure to show a **Field Name** and **Field Value** column along with a unique identifier. Here is a quick example using Tableau's Pivot feature. [Pivot Data](https://imgur.com/a/i8TOVlA).